# Pivot trick Oracle SQL, how to pivot?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a question about pivot, I could do what I wanted to do except Y is showing null instead of 0, I would like to show 0 instead of Y.

my code is

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cr.report_id) report_id, cr.contact_type'
FROM contact_report cr
WHERE cr.contact_type IN ('A','P','Y','B')
GROUP BY cr.contact_type
```

it shows

```
report_id cr.contact_type
2         P
4         A
1         B
```

THEN I use a pivot

```
  SELECT * FROM
                    (
                    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cr.report_id) report_id, cr.contact_type
                    FROM contact_report cr
                    WHERE cr.contact_type IN ('A','P','Y','B')
                    GROUP BY cr.contact_type
                    )
                    PIVOT
                    (SUM(report_id) FOR contact_type IN (
                                  'A' 
                                  'P' 
                                  'Y' 
                                  'B'
```

I get what I want really close

OUTPUT1

```
 A   P   Y   B
 4   2       1
```

question 1

I use Sum function to just show in the pivot. MAX aggregate function also works. which is appropriate to use to show OUTPUT 1, do I still have to use pivot to show like OUTPUT1

question 2

Y is showing null, how can I code nvl(,0) to show Y as 0 in the pivot.

Thank you so much

Have a wonderful day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
with dat as (
    select 2 as report_id,'P' as contact_type from dual
    union all
    select 4 as report_id,'A' as contact_type from dual
    union all
    select 1 as report_id,'B' as contact_type from dual
)
select nvl(A,0) as A, nvl(B,0) as B, nvl(P,0) as P, nvl(Y,0) as Y
from (
  select report_id, contact_type from dat
)
PIVOT
(
  max(report_id) for contact_type in ('A'as"A",'B'as"B",'P'as"P",'Y'as"Y")
);
```

Output:

```
A   B   P   Y
4   1   2   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your pivoted columns aliases in the `IN (...)` clause you can refer to them explicitly in the main select list, and apply `nvl` or `coalesce`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, 0) as a,
  COALESCE(p, 0) as p,
  COALESCE(y, 0) as y,
  COALESCE(b, 0) as b
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cr.report_id) report_id, cr.contact_type
  FROM contact_report cr
  WHERE cr.contact_type IN ('A','P','Y','B')
  GROUP BY cr.contact_type
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(report_id)
  FOR contact_type IN (
    'A' as a, 
    'P' as p, 
    'Y' as y, 
    'B' as b
  )
);

         A          P          Y          B
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4          2          0          1
```

Well, you don't *have* to alias them, but using the defaults:

```
SELECT COALESCE("'A'", 0) as a,
  COALESCE("'P'", 0) as p,
  COALESCE("'Y'", 0) as y,
  COALESCE("'B'", 0) as b
FROM (
...
```

is a bit harder to work with.

In this case it doesn't really matter whether you use `sum` or `max`, but I think it would be more usual to go with `max`.